# Adding column to group by clause messes up counting

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to count the number of duplicates in a column, which works when done like this:

```
SELECT CorrelationId, Count(CorrelationId) as total
FROM VoipDetailsView
WHERE ResponseCode = 200
GROUP BY CorrelationId
```

However, when I try to add other columns to the result

```
SELECT SessionIdTime, CorrelationId, Count(CorrelationId) as total
FROM VoipDetailsView
WHERE ResponseCode = 200
GROUP BY CorrelationId, SessionIdTime
ORDER BY SessionIdTime
```

All the counts are now 0 or 1 even though (or possibly because) the duplicate values are being displayed now. I don't mind the repetition but I need the last column to contain the total number of duplicate CorrelationIds for every one selected. (So for instance if the value exists twice, the count would be 2 for both of those rows)

What kind of query do I need to do this?

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results. How do you really want to group SessionIdTime? If you have two rows for the same correlationID, what SessionIdTime do you want to show? The earliest, the latest, the average, the date without time, something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate the aggregation of CorrelationId into a separate query and join that with your table to fetch other columns, something like:

```
SELECT v.SessionIdTime, v.CorrelationId, total
From VoipDetailsView v inner join
(SELECT CorrelationId, Count(CorrelationId) as total
FROM VoipDetailsView
WHERE ResponseCode = 200
GROUP BY CorrelationId) agg
on v.CorrelationId = agg.CorrelationId
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using an aggregate function on the `SessionIdTime` column like `min()`

```
SELECT min(SessionIdTime), CorrelationId, Count(CorrelationId) as total
FROM VoipDetailsView
WHERE ResponseCode = 200
GROUP BY CorrelationId
ORDER BY min(SessionIdTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second query gives you the number of duplicates CorrelationId in a specific SessionIdTime, is it what you want ? What does the SessionIdTime mean ?

Btw, you can do like this :

```
SELECT CorrelationId, Count(*) as total
FROM VoipDetailsView
WHERE ResponseCode = 200
GROUP BY CorrelationId;
```

it's a bit more optimized